# Changing Height of column in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a table that has certain values, for each column I have to calculate a percentage and plot a row with all the percentages. In that row each column should have same background color but the height of background color should be based on the percentage value of that column. If `50%` is the value then the column should be say half green and half white. 
I am using `d3`. Can any one help plz

```
var td_avg = tr.select("ab")
        .data(getAvg)
        .enter()
        .append("td")
        .text(function(k) {return (Math.round((k/(arr.length-1))*100)+ "%");})
        .attr("height", function(k) {return (Math.round((k/(arr.length-1))*100)+ "%");})
        .style("background-color", "green");
```

Comment: It sounds like you would need to add another element to show the colour with the desired height. Or do a bar chart.

Comment: I have a followup question, What can i do to vary the width of each column based on some other random value in  a table

Comment: At this point it may be better to create the table in SVG and position each cell explicitly.